# download files with user name and password using axel downloader not accepting special characters like ; : < >

Tags: wget

When I download files with user name and password using axel downloader it will download.

**Working Example**

```
axel.exe  http://mathanraj:78tyu@xxxx.com/xxx.zip  (no probleam)
```

but the problem is if password has special characters like `;`, `:`, `<`, or `>` axel downloader is not accepting it.

**Not Working Example**

```
axel.exe  http://mathanraj:78tyu;;@xxxx.com/xxx.zip (here only probleam)
```

How can I use special characters like `;`, `:`, `<`, or `>` in password for download using  axel downloader.

Answer (score 7):

I had the similar problem and mine resolved using `\` before any special character.
However there is another way of doing this which I prefer. You can use the Header option to add HTTP Authorization header which helps you not to express your username and password in plain text.

For this first you need to convert your credentials into base64, it's like this on Unix-like sytems:

`echo -n "username:password" | openssl base64`

Don't forget the `-n` option to not to print the trailing newline character. You also need to use `\` like before for the special characters.

Then you can use axel in this way:

`axel -H "Authorization: Basic base64HashValue" "yourURL"`

Hope it solves your problem. ;)

Answer (score 2):

I would expect url-encoding to work -- use a percent (%) followed by the hex value for each character.  Adding single quotes around the URL is probably a good idea as well.

`axel.exe  'http://mathanraj:78tyu%3B%3B@xxxx.com/xxx.zip'`

Comment: I'm not familiar with axel, you might have to report the issue to those developers, or check their documentation.

Comment: Sorry, I know this an old thread. But this isn't working for me. Although, it does download a 'file', but the file contains some HTML which looks like a simple HTML form asking me to enter a username and password. Even though I supply the password as a base64 hash! I can download the actual file I want to download using wget just fine, but it's 300MB and takes a long time in one thread.

Answer (score 2):

Try putting the password between marks ( **' '** ), like this:

```
axel.exe  http://mathanraj:'78tyu;;'@xxxx.com/xxx.zip
```

Just tried on linux and it worked.